# SpecificationExecutor.delete does not delete related entities with Cascade.ALL

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have following entities.

```java
@Entity
public class Demand {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "demand", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Alternative> alternatives = new ArrayList<>();

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public List<Alternative> getAlternatives() {
        return alternatives;
    }

    public void setAlternatives(List<Alternative> alternatives) {
        this.alternatives = alternatives;
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
public class Alternative {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_demand_alternative"), nullable = false)
    private Demand demand;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Demand getDemand() {
        return demand;
    }

    public void setDemand(Demand demand) {
        this.demand = demand;
    }
}
```

repository

```java
public interface DemandRepository extends JpaRepository<Demand, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Demand> {

    interface Specs {

        static Specification<Demand> byId(final String id) {
            return (root, query, cb) -> cb.equal(root.get(Demand_.id), id);
        }
    }
}
```

and the test

```java
@SpringBootTest
class SpecificationIssueTest {

    @Autowired
    private DemandRepository demandRepository;

    @Test
    void deleteCascadeWorks() {
        final Demand okDelete = demandWithAlternatives();
        final Demand okDeleteById = demandWithAlternatives();
        final Demand noOkDelete = demandWithAlternatives();

        demandRepository.saveAll(List.of(okDelete, okDeleteById, noOkDelete));

        assertDoesNotThrow(() -> demandRepository.delete(okDelete));
        assertDoesNotThrow(() -> demandRepository.deleteById(okDeleteById.getId()));

        assertDoesNotThrow(() -> demandRepository.delete(DemandRepository.Specs.byId(noOkDelete.getId())));
    }

    private Demand demandWithAlternatives() {
        final Demand demand = new Demand();
        demand.setId(id());
        demand.setAlternatives(List.of(alternative(demand), alternative(demand)));
        return demand;
    }

    private Alternative alternative(final Demand demand) {
        final Alternative alt = new Alternative();
        alt.setId(id());
        alt.setDemand(demand);
        return alt;
    }

    private String id() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

}
```

spring boot version is `3.0.6`.

There is problem on the last line of test method `assertDoesNotThrow(() -> demandRepository.delete(DemandRepository.Specs.byId(noOkDelete.getId())));`. I'd like to delete all related entities but `delete` method from `JpaSpecificationExecutor` doesn't lookup them and even throws error:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_DEMAND_ALTERNATIVE: PUBLIC.ALTERNATIVE FOREIGN KEY(DEMAND_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.DEMAND(ID) ('b8f1d8e8-af65-4436-aaab-9e2fc1f9c2eb')"; SQL statement:
delete from demand where id=? [23503-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:508)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:365)
```

Is there any way how I can delete related entities with `JpaSpecificationExecutor.delete` with respect to `Cascade.ALL`?

Comment: created [github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2936)